# How to open the Word from the web browser and send data so that I can get in my Add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

What I want is I can open the Word when I click a button from the web browser, as the same time, I can send data to the Word. The data will be used in my Word Add-in. But I can not find a practical scheme in the document.

I just can create a Add-in according to the official documentation instructions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.